# Bilingual (English and Arabic) websites for same domain by using single html structure?

Tags: html, css, multilingual

I am designing a bilingual websites(English and Arabic) by using single html and multiple css. I created a button and apply script to flip all the divs for Arabic website.

What i really want is that all the pages should render in Arabic after click this button. Right now it is working for single page.

Comment: Set a cookie to remember the language preference?

Comment: i18n (internationalization) is the process of designing a web page tu support multiple locales.  Provide more information about what are your technology stack you are using? Are you using ASP.net or Lavarel or Symfony?

Comment: you must store your keyword in both language to your storage. or use google translator.

Answer (score 1):

I am also working on the bilingual website that make the changes on button click. I have stored the selected language in the local storage. You can set the default language to English and when you change the value in the language drop down it resets the key.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a cookie or session variable to store the language selected. And check for it in each page to determine which css file to be loaded.